# Why matlab returns a damp ratio as 1 for a over damped system?

Tags: control-engineering, matlab

I have a second order system with the transfer function as: "1/(s^2 + 5.45s + 1)", I thought it should be an over-damped system, but when I use the damp function in MatLab, it returns the damp ratio zeta as 1 with 2 different natural frequency, what does that mean?

">> $display(G6)$

$G6 = \dfrac{1}{s^2 + 5.45s +1}$

Continuous-time transfer function.

> > $damp(G6)$

Eigenvalue     Damping     Frequency

-1.90e-01      1.00e+00     1.90e-01
-5.26e+00      1.00e+00     5.26e+00

(Frequencies expressed in rad/seconds)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Matlab doumentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.damp.html#mw_774bba0d-fc75-4b75-a377-8ab21de1d8ee), the damping is calculated *per pole*. and it is given by the formula

$$
\zeta = -\cos(\angle s)
$$
where s is the pole location. Since both poles of an over damped system are on the (negative) real axis, the damping is 1 for both poles.

For over damped systems, the poles are purely real and one cannot *naturally* pair the poles as in the case of complex conjugates. This may be why Matlab decides to report the damping *per pole*.